# Calculate SUM between two dates SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having two tables

Calendar

```
FirstDate   |  LastDate
------------+-----------    
2020-05-01     2020-05-03
2020-05-02     2020-05-04
```

ProfileRate

```
ID |    Date    | Rate | Product
---+------------+------+----------
1    2020-05-01   100    Prod1
2    2020-05-02   200    Prod1
3    2020-05-03   300    Prod1
4    2020-05-04   400    Prod1
5    2020-05-01   150    Prod2
6    2020-05-02   250    Prod2
7    2020-05-03   350    Prod2
8    2020-05-04   450    Prod2
```

I want to calculate SUM. Something like this

```
FirstDate   | LastDate    | Prod1  | Prod2 
------------+-------------+--------+-------
2020-05-01    2020-05-03    600      750
2020-05-02    2020-05-04    900      1050
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT [Date], SUM([Rate])
FROM [ProfileRate]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-04'
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You're grouping by `[date]` so you're going to get 1 row for the value of each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do several steps to solve the problem:

1. combine calendar records with profiles
2. establish which profiles meet the calendar range
3. total the value for each profile and date range
4. finally establish the detailed information of the calendar

this query meets the conditions

```
with DataForCalendar as
(
  SELECT IdCalendar,FirstDate,LastDate,Id,DateRate,Rate,Product
  FROM
  Calendar CROSS JOIN ProfileRate 
  where DateRate  between '2020-05-01' and '2020-05-05'
),
DetailForCalendar as 
(
  select IdCalendar,Rate,Product 
  from DataForCalendar
  where   DateRate between FirstDate and LastDate
),
TotalForCalendar as 
(
  select IdCalendar,Product,sum(Rate)As Total from DetailForCalendar
  GROUP BY IdCalendar,Product
)
select   Calendar.IdCalendar,Calendar.FirstDate,Calendar.LastDate,
TotalForCalendar.Product,TotalForCalendar.Total 
from TotalForCalendar inner join 
Calendar on TotalForCalendar.IdCalendar=Calendar.IdCalendar;
```

[in this example you can find step by step how it work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c080d7/17)

in this example there is one more product and one more calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a `JOIN` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.FirstDate, c.LastDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pr.prod = 'Prod1' THEN pr.Rate END) as prod1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pr.prod = 'Prod2' THEN pr.Rate END) as prod2
FROM Calender c LEFT JOIN
     ProfileRate pr
     ON pr.Date >= c.FirstDate AND pr.Date <= c.LastDate
GROUP BY c.FirstDate, c.LastDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. What if N number of Products are there???

Comment: Then you would have a separate `SUM()` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Do the join & conditional aggregation :

```
select c.fisrtdate, c.lastdate,
       sum(case when pr.product = 'prod1' then rate else 0 end) as prod1,
       sum(case when pr.product = 'prod2' then rate else 0 end) as prod2
from calendar c join
     ProfileRate pr
     on pr.date >= c.fisrtdate and pr.date <= c.lastdate
group by c.fisrtdate, c.lastdate;
```

If you want all calendar dates then use `left` join instead.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. What if N number of Products are there??? And I don't want to hardcode

Comment: @Aemash. . . Then you need dynamic `pivot`.